# How to close WebSockets properly from Application class?

Tags: java, websocket

I am using WebSockets for my chat app in android. For convenience, I am creating the connection in Application class so that it can be used by activities and fragments with one instance. Here is the code for my Application class:

```
public class Main extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    private static WeakReference<Context> context;
    private WebSocket webSocket;
    private final Request request;
    private final OkHttpClient client;
    public static final int SOCKET_CLOSE_CODE = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = new WeakReference<>(getApplicationContext());
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        this.client = new OkHttpClient();
        this.request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://192.168.1.9:8080").build();
    }

    public void connect() {
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
                super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
            }
        });
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void onResume() {
        if (webSocket == null) return;
        connect();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void onPause() {
        if (webSocket == null) return;
        disconnect();
    }
    
    private void disconnect() {
      webSocket.close(SOCKET_CLOSE_CODE, null);
      webSocket = null;
    }


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (client == null) return;
        client.connectionPool().evictAll();
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the socket does not close in either onPause or onDestroy (tried both). I am using Ratchet in server side. What's wrong with this code? Note that I want to close the connection exactly from the Application class itself instead of closing from activities or fragments or any other components.

Comment: `ProcessLifecycleOwner` does not use `ON_DESTROY` -- see [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner). Beyond that, you may need to close the websocket on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be `WebSocketActivity extends FragmentActivity implements WebSocketListener {}` because `Activity` would implement these lifecycle methods, therefore they can be overridden.

Comment: onPause/onStop is called without an issue in the Application class. It's not an issue with the lifecycle but rather closing the WebSockets. I tried closing it from the activity as you mentioned but the issue persists. And as I said, I need to open and close the connection from the Application class itself for maintaining a single instance for the entire application.

Comment: `android:singleTop="true"` eqals one single instance. There is no log and nothing, therefore I can only assume, they you probably should remove these `final` keywords.